# Can I sync the Subscriber status from SFMC to Service Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am looking for a way to synch the Subscriber Status from SFMC to SC so that it can be displayed on the Contact records. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you using Contact ID as Subscriber Key in MC? Then it should be done automatically, when a subscriber unsubscribes.

Comment: Thanks, Lukas. Global opt out gets synced automatically, but I am specifically trying to expose Held status.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. Query _Subscribers and populate a DE with the relating status
2. Write a Script activity to loop through the DE and use the UpdateSingleSalesforceObject OR CreateSalesforceObject AMPScript functions to update Salesforce
3. Put these 2 steps into an automation to run on a schedule

   - Note you'll need to manage the 2k row limit of the call and plan for extra records post 2k